# Crystal Report - how to return records where field needs to match multiple values

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am running Crystal Reports version XI. I have a table "PatientRecords", which has the following columns name, dob, health programs, address etc. I want to return all the patient's names where health programs they only have APS or they have APS and TCS. A patient may appear multiple times in the table with different health programs. All the possible health programs are APS, TCS, SELF and/or SPARK.

In crystal reports record formula, i tried to type:

```
{PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" or
({PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" and {PatientRecords.coverage}="TCS")
```

This gives me only people with APS only programs but it doesn't return any patients that have both APS and TCS. How do I get Crystal Reports to return the correct data?

```
Sample data: 
    John Smith, 03-21-1976, APS, 123 Test Way, Visit 1
    Jane Murai, 02-15-1965, TCS, 2312 Apple Way, Visit 1
    Richard Sams, 05-30-1985, APS, 33 Bans Way, Visit 1
    John Smith, 03-21-1976, TCS, 123 Test Way, Visit 2
    Jane Murai, 02-15-1965, APS, 2312 Apple Way, Visit 2
```

So each patient visit is a record and each record can have different coverages, either APS, TCS, SELF or SPARK. So a person can appear MULTIPLE times, but with different coverages.

Comment: Some sample data is needed - currently it is hard to understand, have you multiple programs in same record (field value like "APS, TCS") or on multiple records?

Comment: try changing the order of your criteria ({PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" and {PatientRecords.coverage}="TCS") or
{PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS"

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't filter on the coverage - depend on suppression for this
2. Group by the person (even if you don't show the group)
3. Create functions to represent each coverage as a number like this:

   {@APS}:if {PatientRecords.coverage} = "APS" then 1 else 0
4. Use summary functions calculated at the person's group level to determine suppression of the detail line, like this:

   if max({@APS},{PatientRecords.Name) = 1) and max({@TCS},PatientRecords.Name) = 1 then false else true

The true/false may look backward, but true means to suppress.